# Conditional and joint distribution of the sum of exponential RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$ random variables and $Y_k =\sum^{k}_{i=1}X_i$, $k = 1,2,...,n$.

a) Find the joint PDF of $Y_1,...,Y_n$.

b) Find the conditional PDF of $Y_k$ conditioned on $Y_1,....,Y_{k−1}$, for $k = 2,3,...,n$.

c) Show that $Y_1,...,Y_k$ conditioned on $Y_{k+1},...,Y_n$ is uniformly distributed over a subset in $\Bbb{R}^k$, for $k = 1,2,...,n−1$. Find this subset.

My attempt:

For $\lambda_i = \lambda$, $\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i \sim Erlang(n,\lambda) $, thus $Y_k\sim Erlang(k,\lambda)$

From here I need to find the CDF first to find the PDF. But I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

**Begin here:**

Since for all $2 \leq k\leq n$ we have $X_k=Y_k-Y_{k-1}$, and the $(X_k)$ are iid expnentially distributed with pdf $f_{\small X}(x)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda x)\cdotp\mathbf 1_{0\leq x}$ ... therefore... $$\begin{align}f_{\small Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n}(y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_n)&=f_{\small X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(y_1,y_2{-}y_1,\ldots,y_n{-}y_{n-1})\\[1ex]&= f_{\small X}(y_1)\prod_{k=2}^nf_{\small X}(y_k-y_{k-1})\\[2ex]&=\lambda^n\exp\left(-\lambda\left(y_1+\sum_{k=2}^n(y_k-y_{k-1})\right)\right)\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq\ldots\leq y_n}\\[2ex]&=\phantom{\lambda^n\exp(-\lambda y_n)\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq\ldots\leq y_n}}\end{align}$$

Comment: How come $f_{Y_1,...,Y_n}(y_1,...,y_n) = f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: @SharonZh . Consider for $n=2$... $$\begin{align}\{Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2\}&=\{X_1=y_1, X_1+X_2=y_2\}\\[1ex]&=\{X_1=y_1, X_2=y_2-y_1\}\end{align}$$So $$f_{\small Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=f_{\small X_1,X_2}(y_1, y_2-y_1)$$

Comment: After following your prompt, I found: $$f_{Y_1,...,Y_n}(y_1,...,y_n) = \lambda exp(-\lambda y_n)$$  for the b) using: $$f_{Y_k|Y_{1},...,Y_{k-1}}(y_k|y_{1},...,y_{k-1})=\frac{f_{Y_1,..,Y_k}(y_1,...,y_k)}{f_{Y_k}(y_k) }$$ I got: $$f_{Y_k|Y_1,...,Y_{k-1}}(y_k|y_1,...,y_{k-1}) = (k-1)!(\lambda y_k)^{1-k}$$ and for c) using $$f_{Y_1,..,Y_k|Y_{k+1},...,Y_{n}}(y_1,...,y_k|y_{k+1},...,y_{n})=\frac{f_{Y_1,..,Y_n}(y_1,...,y_n)}{f_{Y_1,...,Y_k}(y_1,...,y_k-1) }$$ I got $$\frac{1}{exp(\lambda(y_n-y_k))}$$ the question continue to ask me to find the subset where it is uniformly distributed. How?